# How can I filter a report with duplicate fields in related records?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report where I need to filter out records where there is a duplicate contract number within the same station but a different date. It is not considered a duplicate value becuase of the different date. I then need to summarize the costs and count the contracts but even if i suppress the "duplicate fields" it will summarize the value. I want to select the record with the most current date.

```
Station Trans-DT  Cost    Contract-No
   8    5/11/2010  10         5008
   8    5/12/2010  15         5008
   9    5/11/2010  12         5012
   9    5/15/2010  50         5012
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a group on Contract-No.
2. Create a formula field to display most recent Trans-DT.
   Something like:  `Maximum ({Trans-DT}, {Command.Contract-No})`
3. Create your summary fields or running totals based on the newly created Contract-No group.

Edit:
To summarize costs and count contracts, you'll need a bit of trickery.

Add this (in a formula field) to the report header section:

```
// start the sum
// put in report header
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global NumberVar TotalCost := 0;
```

This goes in the report footer:

```
// final count
// put in report footer
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global NumberVar TotalCost;
TotalCost;
```

And place this in a formula field within your Contract-No or Station group:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global NumberVar TotalCost;
if {Command.Trans-DT} = maximum({Command.Trans-DT}, {Command.Contract-No}) then
    TotalCost := TotalCost + {Command.Cost}
else
    TotalCost;
```

I'll leave the counting part to you.  Good luck!

Comment: I have it grouped by contract now, formula field was ok, but when I create a summary it still adds both values from station 8 to the total. I just want it to display 15 and its displaying 25. Once I get that working, I have to total all the totals from station 8 per week

Comment: Should I be grouping by station first instead?

Comment: Missed a conditional statement in the last code snippet.  Fixed now.